# PHP form data not submitting with recaptcha

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

I'm having some trouble setting up the recaptha with my limited PHP knowledge.  I have managed to get it working in essence, but am finding that know my form data is not submitting.

Here is the PHP as it stands:

```
<?php
$sendToEmail="my@emailaddress.co.uk";    

$yourname = $_POST["yourname"];
$timecall = $_POST["timecall"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$phone=$_POST["phone"];
$message=$_POST["message"];    


$content =  "Time to Call : " . $timecall . "<br>";
$content .=  "Name : " . $yourname . "<br>";
$content .=  "Email : " . $email . "<br>";
$content .=  "Phone : " . $phone . "<br>";
$content .= "Message : ". $message ."<br>";    


$senderEmailId = "Reply-To: $email";
$senderEmailId = "From: $email\r\n";
$senderEmailId .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$subject ="New Enquiry from the website";    

    if(isset($_POST['ContactButton'])) {    

          $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
          $privatekey = "--private-key--";    

          $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST[g-recaptcha-response]."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);    

         $data = json_decode($response);    

        if (isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true) {    

//// True- what happens when user is verified    

  header("Location:thankyou.php?CaptchaPass=True");    


        }else{    

  header("Location:thankyou.php?CaptchaFail=True");

        }
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

PHP 101: array key strings which aren't quoted are treated as undefined constants. You have:

```
$_POST[g-recaptcha-response]
```

which is parsed/executed as

```
$_POST[g minus recaptcha minus response]
$_POST[0 minus 0 minus 0]
$_POST[0]
```

If you had PHP's debug options enabled (`error_reporting`, `display_errors`), you'd have been given warnings about this. These settings should NEVER be off on a debug/devel server in the first place.

Try

```
$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']
       ^--------------------^
```

instead. Note the quotes.